# How to combine data from api into domain objects using RxJava2?

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2

I have the following code:

```
interface UsersApi {
  fun getUsers() : Single<List<UserTO>>
  fun getPosts(postId: String) : Single<PostTO>
}
data class UserTO(val name: String, postIds: List<String>)
data class PostTO(val title: String, val content: String)
data class User(val name: String, val posts: List<Post>)
data class Post(val title: String, content: String)
```

I am trying to write a repository class with a method that returns

```
Single<List<User>>
```

But I have no idea how to do it, since I need access to earlier objects in the stream and also the `Single` is confusing things.

I am pretty sure I have to start with a call to `getUsers` followed by a flatmap, but then the things get confusing.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to load your users from the API and for each user load their posts then you could do something like the following.

`flattenAsFlowable` allows you to iterate each UserTO from your api response. With this you can extract their postIds and map to the User object.

`Flowable.fromIterable` allows you to iterate over the postIds collection and perform the api call for each post.

```
class MyRepository(private val api: UsersApi) {

    fun getUsers(): Single<List<User>> {
        return api.getUsers()
            .flattenAsFlowable { it }
            .flatMapSingle { loadUserPosts(it) }
            .toList()
    }

    private fun loadUserPosts(user: UserTO): Single<User> {
        return loadPosts(user.postIds)
            .map { User(name = user.name, posts = it) }
    }

    private fun loadPosts(postIds: List<String>): Single<List<Post>> {
        return Flowable.fromIterable(postIds)
            .flatMapSingle { api.getPosts(it) }
            .map { Post(title = it.title, content = it.content) }
            .toList()
    }
}
```